# Steering suddenly has become very loose

Tags: vw, golf, steering

I have a Mk1 Golf (no power steering). Today I was pulling a hard right to do a U turn and heard a slight clunk. Now the steering is very loose and unaligned. You almost have to turn the wheel 45 degrees either direction for anything to happen.

Would anyone know what I should be looking for to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it was because a bolt holding the steering rack in place had sheared.

Very dangerous and glad I decided to visit a mechanic!

Answer (score 2):

I had this in one of my Mk1 Golf GTI's and what had actually happened was that the bulkhead had corroded and the steering rack mount came away from the bulkhead which caused the steering column to disconnect from the rack thus loosing all steering.  Thankfully it happened at a low speed.

Definitely a weak point on the Mk1 Golf and anyone else reading this ought to be aware and inspect theirs carefully.